# Taking 2 values and performing a bitwise AND Visual basic

Tags: vb.net, bitwise-operators, subnet

So right now I am able to grab a decimal number and convert it to an 8-bit binary number. What i was looking to do was to perform a Bit wise AND to match the values. for example if I have a value of 192 and i want to Bit wise AND with 255.

Val1 = 11000000

Val2 = 11111111

ValFinal = 11000000

is there a function to do this?

Comment: You need to ask a question.

Comment: Why don't you read it here? --- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz3k228a.aspx

Comment: I generally wonder, why ask here if there is MSDN documentation that clearly explains how to do it?

Comment: a) non professionals often dont know the right terms to find the article b) they also often do not understand MSDN c) MSDN is often more general and would require thinking to apply the content to the problem d) some people need to be spoon fed the answer e) sometimes SO is quicker and wont cut into critical video game/TV/porn surfing time